# QT - Includepath with an "include" as a directory wont include

Tags: c++, qt, include

I'm trying to add the header file afxwin.h to my QT project. The include path I added to my project file is below.

INCLUDEPATH += C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include

This is not behaving correctly, as it does not include the headers I'm looking for.

It highlights the "include" portion of the path in Red and when hovering over it displays;

*include(filename)*

*[Conditional]*

*Includes the contents of the file specified by filename into the current project at the point where it is included. This function succeeds if filename is included; otherwise it fails. The included file is processed immediately*

Is there a way to escape the include ? I have tried double quotes and it appears to have no effect. Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually double qutoes should work, but if they don't work for what reason ever you can always try using the old 8.3 format:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.0\VC\atlmfc\include
```

Keep in mind it isn't necessarily `~1` all the time, it could as well be `~2`, `~3` etc.
You can use `dir /x /p` on `C:` and `C:\Program Files (x86)` in order to find out the short names for "Program Files (x86)" and "Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0".